# Android Studio: Unexpected top level exception (finished with non-zero exit value 2..)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When i'm trying to debug my android app i'm getting the following error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 2

The error first appeared on adding a new dependency.
This is my gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
// Icepick
compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.1.0'
provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.1.0'
// Mosby
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.parcelableplease:annotation:1.0.1'
apt 'com.hannesdorfmann.parcelableplease:processor:1.0.1'

compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.4.2@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.4.2@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v13:1.4.2@aar'
```

The error appears when i'm trying to use the smarttablayout.
Using the gradle 1.4 Version. Does anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just had the issue yesterday. I fixed it by manually removing the `build/` and `app/build/` folders, and by building the project again.

But it also might come from something else like your app reaching the [65k methods limit](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) (in what case "[Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)" will fix your issue). So you will need to provide the full Graddle log for us to be able to check more in detail what the issue could be.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue when transferring an Android Studio project to another computer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, solved it by doing the following

In the app build gradle file, inside android:
add in defaultConfig:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and add this in the android:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25006428/2069407

Answer (score 0):

At my case change buildToolsVersion from "24" to "23.0.2", solve the problem especially if you're using old Android Studio less than version 2