# Execution failed. App transform classes with dex for debug

Tags: java, gradle, execution

Error:Execution failed for task

```
> ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean your Gradle dependencies. if it doesn't work you can use "multiDexEnabled true" in Gradle.

There's a lot of info about this question ;)

EDIT:

link #1: http://frogermcs.github.io/MultiDex-solution-for-64k-limit-in-Dalvik/

link #2: [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException with android google play services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007289/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception-with-android-google-play-serv)

Comment: If there is 'a lot of info', could you provide links? This will make it easier for other users when they have the same problem.

Comment: sure! a great link is this one http://frogermcs.github.io/MultiDex-solution-for-64k-limit-in-Dalvik/ and another good link is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007289/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception-with-android-google-play-serv

Comment: Indeed, great links! Would you mind adding them to your answer?